# finite sum of riemann function

Tags: sequences-and-series

find a closed form for the sum of the zeta function $\zeta(k)$ for $k$ runs from $1$ to $n$.
I need this to find the sum of an infinite series involving the zeta function at the natural numbers. Any help is nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aren't very specific with what you're asking, I only have a vague idea of what you might be looking for so I will give you a couple things. I think what you're asking for is the following:

Faulhaber's Formula:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^x=\frac{1}{x+1}\sum_{k=0}^x \binom{x+1}{k}B_kn^{x+1-k}
$$
where $B_k$ are the Bernoulli numbers. Of course, these provide good approximations when the powers are in the integers. Generally, you'd need [Euler-Maclaurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). These sums also have expressions using generalized harmonic numbers.

Depending on the context in which you are working, you may find one or more of the following useful:

$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \zeta(n)-1=1
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(2n+1)-1=\frac{1}{4}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(2n)-1=\frac{3}{4}
$$

And of course, I'm assuming you know the [Hurwitz Zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function):
$$
\zeta(s,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(q+n)^s}
$$